# How to call firebase query while leaving page in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dispose

I am trying to call firebase updated query while leaving and joining particular page in flutter, for joining I pass function in initstate() and it's work's fine, but code not working while leaving page using dispose() function but its showing errors. Is there any method available for doing this

```
@override
      void dispose() {
        // TODO: implement dispose
        super.dispose();
        _clearcount();
      }
    
      void _clearcount() async {
        CurrentUser _currentuser = Provider.of<CurrentUser>(context, listen: false);
        CurrentGroup _currentgroup =
            Provider.of<CurrentGroup>(context, listen: false);
        await Firestore.instance
            .collection("groups")
            .document(_currentgroup.getCurrentGroup.id)
            .collection("group_member")
            .document(_currentuser.getCurrentUser.uid)
            .updateData({
          'new_message_count': 0,
        });
      }
```

//Error shown as follows

```
E/flutter ( 7224): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter ( 7224): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
 E/flutter ( 7224): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method
```

Answer (score 1):

_clearcount is doing work and you've asked it to stop, that is why you are getting the error. Dispose is not async.

Suggest that you make _clearcount() return a Future and put a return at the end of it.

There is probably a place where you dismiss the screen, this is where you should put

```
await  _clearcount()
```